# SQL query problem in 'login' script confusing situation

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I've got a problem with PHP, with WampServer. I'm doing such think first time of my life and I'm really confused, because every example I found is not working at all, or I'm getting no output. Could you please help?

```
enter code<?php
require_once "connect.php";

$connection = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

//if($connection->connect_error)
//{
//  echo "Nie można połączyć się z bazą danych";
////} else
//{
    $mail = isset('$_POST[mail]');
    $haslo = isset('$_POST[haslo]');

    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='$mail' AND haslo='$haslo'";
    if ($result = @$connection->query($sql))
    {
        $user = $result->num_rows;
        if($user>0)
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $user =  $row['mail'];

            header('Location:user.php');
            $result->close();
        } else {
            echo"Podałeś złe dane";
        }
    }
    $connection->close();
//  }
?>
```

Comment: `sql` should be `$sql` (missing $)

Comment: isset checks if theres a value and then assign it to variable. $mail = $_POST['mail'] after checking isset

Comment: Also take a look at what `isset()` does/returns

Comment: Please don't use `@` as a silencer in code.

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz appreciate you're help - sometimes this "$" is invisible xD

Comment: You need to use prepared statements.   `isset()` on those literal string values will return true or false.

Comment: You should create new connection.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-wampserver/
or use XAMP!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

Please find corrections below in the code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

$connection = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

//if($connection->connect_error)
//{
//  echo "Nie można połączyć się z bazą danych";
////} else
//{
    $mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : ''; // Added ternary operatr and properly placed single quotes.
    $haslo = isset($_POST['haslo']) ? $_POST['haslo'] : ''; // Same as above

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='$mail' AND haslo='$haslo'"; // Replaced sql by $sql as pointed out in comments.
    if ($result = $connection->query($sql)) // Removed @ (Error supressor, no need for it.)
    {
        $user = $result->num_rows;
        if($user>0)
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $user =  $row['mail'];

            header('Location:user.php');
            $result->close();
        } else {
            echo"Podałeś złe dane";
        }
    }
    $connection->close();
//  }
?>
```

Comment: Prepared statements are a MUST.

Answer (score 0):

there are some checks that need to update in such a way to get output values for manipulation
**updated**

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

$connection = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

//if($connection->connect_error)
//{
//  echo "Nie można połączyć się z bazą danych";
////} else
//{
    $mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : '';
    $haslo = isset($_POST['haslo']) ? $_POST['haslo'] : '';

    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='$mail' AND haslo='$haslo'";
    if ($result = @$connection->query($sql))
    {
        $user = $result->num_rows;
        if(isset($user) && $user > 0)
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $user =  $row['mail'];

            header('Location:user.php');
            $result->close();
        } else {
            echo"Podałeś złe dane";
        }
    }
    $connection->close();
//  }
?>
```

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of the "stfu operator" (`@`). A proper solution will be implementing prepared statements with placeholders and bound variables.

Comment: yes but I only add correct things in existing code not delete anything. as i mentioned **updated** flag